# Initialize Express SQL Server connection leads to infinite page loading

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, express

```
const MSSQLConfig = {
    server: "CatchNotConnected",
    connectionTimeout: 10000,
    requestTimeout: 10000
};

const express = require('express');
const mssql = require('mssql/msnodesqlv8');
const app = express();
app.listen(80);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    async() => {
        try {
            await mssql.connect(MSSQLCONFIG);
            res.send("CONNECTED");
        } catch (e) {
            res.send("NOT CONNECTED");
        }
    }
});
```

The result of this code is that my page is loading for an infinite time instead of showing "NOT CONNECTED" message. Whats wrong?

Comment: why you call `listen` before registering the endpoint `app.get`?

Comment: moreover you are not running the anonymous function inside the route handler. it is defined and not executed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@Manuel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3309466/manuel-spigolon)

This code works fine:

```
const MSSQLConfig = {
    server: "localhost",
    driver: "msnodesqlv8",
    connectionTimeout: 10000,
    requestTimeout: 10000,
    options: {
        trustedConnection: true
    }
};

const express = require('express');
const mssql = require('mssql/msnodesqlv8');
const app = express();

app.get('/', async function(req, res) {
        try {
            await mssql.connect(MSSQLConfig);
            res.send("CONNECTED");
        } catch (e) {
            res.send("NOT CONNECTED");
            console.log(e);
        }
});

app.listen(80);
```